# How can I create my own title frame?

Tags: beamer, titles

I want to build a beamer theme from scratch.
I have read the beameruserguide and I have created files for a inner/outer/font/color-theme, but I still have some difficulties understanding how to create templates, so I'm asking help with this simple title frame customization as an example of how it's done.

By default `\maketitle` will result in

[image]

I simply want to change this and make it result in
[image]

**side-note:**

I still want to declare

```
\title{the title}  
\author{the author}  
\date{\today}
```

for usage in later frames.

Comment: Does it means that you need something like `\supertitle{supertitle}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible implementation: it can actually work with every standard theme, but if the theme you developed puts the title in a box you may wonder to get a different effect.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamerfont{supertitle}{size=\LARGE,parent=structure}    

\makeatletter
\def\supertitle#1{\gdef\@supertitle{#1}}%
\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \begin{centering}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{supertitle}\@supertitle
   \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
  \end{centering}
  \vfill
}
\makeatother

\supertitle{supertitle}
\title{the title}
\author{the author}
\institute{My institute}
\date{\today} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Title of first frame}
text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

The problem I said before is due to the fact that I made use of the `title` color definition for the `beamercolorbox` containing the supertitle.

By means of `\setbeamerfont` it is possible to characterize which are the features of the new template `supertitle`; once given the definition, that should be applied inside the `titlepage` template immediately before the `supertitle` *insertion* to set it with the desired characteristics.

You probably noticed that all elements of the titlepage have this setting. For simplicity, I did not defined a color template for the `supertitle`, but I re-used the definition given by the `title`. Indeed, for each template in the titlepage, there is also a color template definition, that could be given with `\setbeamercolor`. If you want you can define yours by means of:

```
\setbeamercolor{supertitle}{...}
```

After that, you should change the previous definition into:

```
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{supertitle}
  \usebeamerfont{supertitle}\@supertitle
\end{beamercolorbox}
```

For what concern the `\inserttitlegraphic`, it is the command that allows to insert (as the name suggests) the logo just in the titlepage. In your presentation you should use the command:

```
\titlegraphic{...}
```

Comment: Wait, I am confused.
Where does this code go and why is there still an author, institute and date on the titleframe?

Comment: The part between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` should be put in your `innertheme`, while `\setbeamerfont{supertitle}{size=\LARGE,parent=structure}` in the `fonttheme`. I left the other components since you did not say that they should have been removed.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more on what the following commands do: '\usebeamerfont{supertitle}\@supertitle' & '{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}'

Comment: See my updated answer. `:)`